# MQTT for many-to-one communication

Tags: mqtt, sensors

I have an architecture where many sensors (hundreds of them), located in different places (hundreds of kilometers apart), send data to a remote database. Is MQTT suitable for this kind of configurations?.

I was thinking in installing the MQTT broker and my backend in the same server and make the backend subscribe to one topic where all the sensors would be writing. So there would not be any communication between sensor nodes; the communication will be only between each sensor node and the server.

Also, the sensor nodes would be gruped by client (maybe 10 nodes in the same place).

Comment: What makes you think it wouldn't work?

Comment: go here to help you visualize how MQTT works and how to use it ... https://shiftr.io/try ... it is pretty cool

Comment: I was worried about the amount of data that would be redirected to only one node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of thing is perfect for MQTT.

You also don't need to have all the sensors publishing on the same topic, they could all publish to the same topic prefix and the processing app can use a wildcard subscription to have all the messages delivered. Or you can have multiple backend processing apps that split the load by subscribing to different wildecards.

e.g. a topic made up like

```
 country/region/city/sensor-id
```

You could then have different processing apps subscribe to

```
England/#
Scotland/#
USA/Florida/#
USA/California/SanFransico/#
```